# How do I split a column in R into two columns when I have no delimiter?

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataset called data1 that I need to split the first column into two columns. The issue I'm having is that there is no delimiter between what I need to split and the character lengths are different is many rows.

I would like to split it by the date and sex.

E.g

```
12/1/09male
1/9/20female
13/1/19female
4/12/12male
```

I've been trying this but because the values have a different amount of characters I'm stuck.

```
separate(data1, col = 1, into = c("date","sex"), sep = "")
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is a positive look-behind and look-ahead to split on a digit followed by an `"m"` or `"f"`.

```
df %>% separate(1, c("date", "sex"), sep = "(?<=\\d)(?=[mf])")
#    date    sex
#1 12/1/09   male
#2  1/9/20 female
#3 13/1/19 female
#4 4/12/12   male
```

For what it's worth, the same regexp pattern works in base R's `strsplit`

```
setNames(do.call(
    rbind.data.frame,
    strsplit(as.character(df[, 1]), "(?<=\\d)(?=[mf])", perl = T)),
    c("date", "sex"))
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
'12/1/09male
1/9/20female
13/1/19female
4/12/12male')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to R so I am sure this is not the most elegant solution. I first add a comma between the date and sex and then separate on the comma

```
a <- data.frame(row_1 = c("12/1/09male", "1/9/20female", "13/1/19female", "4/12/12male"))
a[, "row_1"] = str_replace(a$row_1, "(male|female)", ",\\1")
separate(a, row_1, ",", into = c("date", "sex"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution using gsub and some regex:

```
df_clean <- within(df, {
    date <- as.Date(gsub("[A-Za-z]+", "", V1), format = "%d/%m/%y")
    sex  <- as.factor(gsub("\\d+|\\/", "", V1))
    rm(V1)
  }
)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/9/20female", 
"12/1/09male", "13/1/19female", "4/12/12male"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::extract`, we can capture data into two parts. First capture the date (in the format d/m/y) and second capture all the remaining part of the string.

```
tidyr::extract(df, V1, c("date", "sex"), "(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)(.*)")

#     date    sex
#1 12/1/09   male
#2  1/9/20 female
#3 13/1/19 female
#4 4/12/12   male
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1/9/20female", 
"12/1/09male", "13/1/19female", "4/12/12male"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```